# segfault during executing gtk application

Tags: ocaml

I' following https://ocaml.org/learn/tutorials/introduction_to_gtk.html
But when I used first code and command:

```
ocamlfind ocamlc -g -package lablgtk2 -linkpkg simple.ml -o simple
```

I got warnings:

```
File "simple.ml", line 8, characters 2-44:
Warning 10: this expression should have type unit.
File "simple.ml", line 18, characters 2-54:
Warning 10: this expression should have type unit.
File "simple.ml", line 23, characters 2-69:
Warning 10: this expression should have type unit.
```

What more when I command: `./simple` I got:

```
(process:7015): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: invalid (NULL) pointer instance

(process:7015): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_signal_connect_data: assertion 'G_TYPE_CHECK_INSTANCE (instance)' failed

(process:7015): Gtk-CRITICAL **: IA__gtk_settings_get_for_screen: assertion 'GDK_IS_SCREEN (screen)' failed

(process:7015): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_object_get: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed

(process:7015): Gtk-CRITICAL **: IA__gtk_settings_get_for_screen: assertion 'GDK_IS_SCREEN (screen)' failed

(process:7015): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_object_get: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed

(process:7015): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_hash_table_lookup: assertion 'hash_table != NULL' failed

(process:7015): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_hash_table_insert_internal: assertion 'hash_table != NULL' failed

(process:7015): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_hash_table_lookup: assertion 'hash_table != NULL' failed

(process:7015): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_hash_table_insert_internal: assertion 'hash_table != NULL' failed

(process:7015): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_hash_table_lookup: assertion 'hash_table != NULL' failed

(process:7015): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_hash_table_lookup: assertion 'hash_table != NULL' failed

(process:7015): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_hash_table_lookup: assertion 'hash_table != NULL' failed

(process:7015): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_hash_table_insert_internal: assertion 'hash_table != NULL' failed

(process:7015): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_hash_table_lookup: assertion 'hash_table != NULL' failed
segfault.
```

Where I am wrong ? After all, it is example from official site.

Comment: it may be from the "officia" site, but the site has collected tutorials on common packages and allows contributions. What versions of the software are you using? (GTK and OCaml)

Answer (score 3):

It looks like the code of the tutorial does not call `lablgtk`'s initializer (which in turn takes care of initializing `gtk`'s internals). According to http://lablgtk.forge.ocamlcore.org/README.html you can simply change your compilation command line to

```
ocamlfind ocamlc -g -package lablgtk2.auto-init -linkpkg simple.ml -o simple
```

Alternatively, you can add the initialization code at the beginning of `simple.ml` directly:

```
let _ = GtkMain.Main.init ()
```